# keep fasta records which have 2 matches of OX values

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that looks as follows :

```
>sp|rin-1 ghsfdhjkuesl OX=10116 GN=Cdh1 PE=1 SV=1|sp|P10287|ghsfdjdeosd gdhkhs OX=10090 GN=Cdh3 PE=1 SV=2
WRDTANWLEINPETGVISTRAEMDREDSEHVKNSTYTALIIATDDGSPIATGTGTLLLVLSDVNDNAPIPEPRNMQFCQRNPKPHVITILDPDLPP
>sp|erin-1 ghsfdshkd OX=10116 GN=Cdh1 PE=1 SV=1|sp|P22223|CADH3_HUMAN Cadherin-3 OX=9606 GN=CDH3 PE=1 SV=2
ESYPTYTLVVQAADLQGEGLSTTAKAVITVKDINDNAPIFNPSTYLQCAASEPCRAVFREAEVTLEAGGAEQEPGQALGKVFMGCPGQEPALFSTD
>sp|n-1 ghsfd OX=10116 GN=Cdh1 PE=1 SV=1|tr|F1LMI3|ghsfdhsj dghe OX=10116 GN=Cdh3 PE=4 SV=3
MGARCRSFSALLLLLQVSSWLCQQPESESDSCRPGFSSEVYTFLVPERHLERGHILGRVKFEGCTGRPRTAFFSEDSRFKVSTDGVITVKRHLKLH
```

I want to keep only those records where there are two matches of OX values,hence,the desired output should like the following :

```
>sp|n-1 ghsfd OX=10116 GN=Cdh1 PE=1 SV=1|tr|F1LMI3|OX=10116 GN=Cdh3 PE=4 SV=3
MGARCRSFSALLLLLQVSSWLCQQPESESDSCRPGFSSEVYTFLVPERHLERGHILGRVKFEGCTGRPRTAFFSEDSRFKVSTDGVITVKRHLKLH
```

The code I have tried is following :

```
awk -v p="OX=" 'FNR==1{x=0}{x+=gsub(p,p);if(x>2){print $line}}' test.fasta
```

Comment: Welcome! You should at least make an attempt to solve the problem. You tagged your question with appropriate tools like `awk` and `sed`, so give them a try.

Comment: @Quasímodo I have included my attempt.I am struggling to frame the awk commands which can partial match the strings starting with OX in a line starting with '>' .If there is a match between OX values in a line,then it obtains the line and next line as well..

Comment: Thanks for the edit. In the sample you provided, `OX=number` always appears in the 3rd and 8th fields in each line starting with `>`. Can one rely on that to sketch a solution, or is that mere coincidence?

Comment: It is coincidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this `awk` script, which seems to work.

```
awk '
    printnext == 1 {                          #Prints the line after the line w 2 matches
        print;
        printnext=0;
    }
    match($0, /OX=[0-9]*/) {                  #Looks for OX=numbers
        id=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);         #Saves it to id
        c=0;
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){                  #Looks for two occurrences of id in line
            if ($i==id){
                c=c+1;
                if (c==2) {print;printnext=1}
            }
        }
    }
' test.fasta
```

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 3):

How about this one, without using loop. Could you please try following. Will add detailed explanation in few mins.

```
awk '
match($0,/OX=[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  if(gsub(val,"&")==2){
    print
    found=1
  }
  val=""
  next
}
found{
  found=""
  print
}
' Input_file
```

OR a small editing in above solution where remove `val=""` part as per @Quasimodo comment:

```
awk '
match($0,/OX=[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  if(gsub(val,"&")==2){
    print
    found=1
  }
  next
}
found{
  found=""
  print
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding a detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/OX=[0-9]+/){              ##Using match function to match OX= digits in current line.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)     ##Creating variable val whose value is sub-string of value of current line starts from RSTART till value of RLENGTH.
  if(gsub(val,"&")==2){             ##Checking condition if value of Global substitutions is equal to 2 then do following.
    print                           ##Printing the current line.
    found=1                         ##Setting variable found value as 1 here.
  }
  val=""                            ##Nullifying variable val here.
  next                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found{                              ##Checking condition if variable found is NOT NULL then do following.
  found=""                          ##Nullifying variable found here.
  print                             ##Printing current line here.
}
'  Input_file                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** NOTE, this code is trying to cover an edge case if anyone's samples are exact same as shown by OP then above codes should be Good enough.

Trying to cover an edge case here mentioned by @kvantour in comments, changed regex a bit where it checks like `OX` should be preceded and followed by a space.

```
awk '
match($0,/\s+OX=[0-9]+\s+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  if(gsub(val,"&")==2){
    print
    found=1
  }
  val=""
  next
}
found{
  found=""
  print
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: I think you could remove `val=""` line as a small improvement. That's a really nice solution anyway, Ravinder!

Comment: @Quasímodo, Thank you for nice words :) For safer side I made it NULL to be honest, I will add that solution which doesn't have it too now cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk, you can use [patsplit](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions) and split by [desired content](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) vs by some delimiter.

Given:

```
$ cat test.fasta
>sp|rin-1 ghsfdhjkuesl OX=10116 GN=Cdh1 PE=1 SV=1|sp|P10287|ghsfdjdeosd gdhkhs OX=10090 GN=Cdh3 PE=1 SV=2
WRDTANWLEINPETGVISTRAEMDREDSEHVKNSTYTALIIATDDGSPIATGTGTLLLVLSDVNDNAPIPEPRNMQFCQRNPKPHVITILDPDLPP
>sp|erin-1 ghsfdshkd OX=10116 GN=Cdh1 PE=1 SV=1|sp|P22223|CADH3_HUMAN Cadherin-3 OX=9606 GN=CDH3 PE=1 SV=2
ESYPTYTLVVQAADLQGEGLSTTAKAVITVKDINDNAPIFNPSTYLQCAASEPCRAVFREAEVTLEAGGAEQEPGQALGKVFMGCPGQEPALFSTD
>sp|n-1 ghsfd OX=10116 GN=Cdh1 PE=1 SV=1|tr|F1LMI3|ghsfdhsj dghe OX=10116 GN=Cdh3 PE=4 SV=3
MGARCRSFSALLLLLQVSSWLCQQPESESDSCRPGFSSEVYTFLVPERHLERGHILGRVKFEGCTGRPRTAFFSEDSRFKVSTDGVITVKRHLKLH
```

You can split and capture by value pairs, in this case by `OX=`:

```
$ awk -v RS=$'>' '{
             cnt=patsplit($0, arr, "OX=[0-9]+") 
             if (cnt==2 && arr[1]==arr[2]) 
                printf ">%s", $0
            }' test.fasta   
>sp|n-1 ghsfd OX=10116 GN=Cdh1 PE=1 SV=1|tr|F1LMI3|ghsfdhsj dghe OX=10116 GN=Cdh3 PE=4 SV=3
MGARCRSFSALLLLLQVSSWLCQQPESESDSCRPGFSSEVYTFLVPERHLERGHILGRVKFEGCTGRPRTAFFSEDSRFKVSTDGVITVKRHLKLH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[O][X][=]' '{a=$0; gsub(/ .*/,"",$2) ; gsub(/ .*/,"",$3) ;  if ($2==$3) print a }'
```

Demo

```
:>cat regular_expressions_are_greedy.txt
>sp|rin-1 ghsfdhjkuesl OX=10116 GN=Cdh1 PE=1 SV=1|sp|P10287|ghsfdjdeosd gdhkhs OX=10090 GN=Cdh3 PE=1 SV=2WRDTANWLEINPETGVISTRAEMDREDSEHVKNSTYTALIIATDDGSPIATGTGTLLLVLSDVNDNAPIPEPRNMQFCQRNPKPHVITILDPDLPP
>sp|erin-1 ghsfdshkd OX=10116 GN=Cdh1 PE=1 SV=1|sp|P22223|CADH3_HUMAN Cadherin-3 OX=9606 GN=CDH3 PE=1 SV=2ESYPTYTLVVQAADLQGEGLSTTAKAVITVKDINDNAPIFNPSTYLQCAASEPCRAVFREAEVTLEAGGAEQEPGQALGKVFMGCPGQEPALFSTD
>sp|n-1 ghsfd OX=10116 GN=Cdh1 PE=1 SV=1|tr|F1LMI3|ghsfdhsj dghe OX=10116 GN=Cdh3 PE=4 SV=3MGARCRSFSALLLLLQVSSWLCQQPESESDSCRPGFSSEVYTFLVPERHLERGHILGRVKFEGCTGRPRTAFFSEDSRFKVSTDGVITVKRHLKLH
:>awk -F'[O][X][=]' '{a=$0; gsub(/ .*/,"",$2) ; gsub(/ .*/,"",$3) ;  if ($2==$3) print a }' regular_expressions_are_greedy.txt
>sp|n-1 ghsfd OX=10116 GN=Cdh1 PE=1 SV=1|tr|F1LMI3|ghsfdhsj dghe OX=10116 GN=Cdh3 PE=4 SV=3MGARCRSFSALLLLLQVSSWLCQQPESESDSCRPGFSSEVYTFLVPERHLERGHILGRVKFEGCTGRPRTAFFSEDSRFKVSTDGVITVKRHLKLH
:>
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F'[O][X][=]'  <---  Setting field separator as  "OX="
'{
a=$0; <-- Saving input record in variable a. ($0 = Means whole records)
gsub(/ .*/,"",$2) ; <-- Removing all character after space from column 1 
gsub(/ .*/,"",$3) ;  <-- Removing all character after space from column 2
if ($2==$3) <-- Checking if 2 values are equal. 
print a 
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

A very quick way would be to do something like this:

```
awk '/^>/{p=0;delete a
          for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) a[$i]++
          for(i in a) if (i ~ /^OX=/ && a[i]>1) p=1
         }
     p' file
```

This will match cases such as:

```
> foobar OX=1 OX=2 OX=3 OX=1
ABCDEF
```

A bit more optimized if you care only about the string `OX=`, you can do:

```
awk '/^>/{p=0;delete a
          for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) if($i ~ /^OX=/) a[$i]++
          for(i in a) if (a[i]>1) p=1
         }
     p' file
```