# Filter alignments where there are two string matches between character _ and /

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have set of alignment files that look like the following :

```
>X2JE30_DROME/180-423|W6URD5_ECHGR/38-170
.........AEGYPVDLYYLMDLSKSM...E..DDKAK..LST....LG.D......K....L......
>X2JE30_DROME/180-410|X1WIK5_DROME/68-211
......AEGYPVDLYYLMDLSKSM...E..DDKAK..LST....LG.D......K....L.........
>X2dhs0_ECHGR/183-490|X1WIK5_ECHGR/68-211
.......AEGYPVDLYYLMDLSKSM...E..DDKAK..LST....LG.D......K....L........
```

How to obtain the following output where the sequence will only print if there is match between  two strings between _ and /:

Desired output

```
>X2JE30_DROME/180-410|X1WIK5_DROME/68-211
......AEGYPVDLYYLMDLSKSM...E..DDKAK..LST....LG.D......K....L.........
>X2dhs0_ECHGR/183-490|X1WIK5_ECHGR/68-211
.......AEGYPVDLYYLMDLSKSM...E..DDKAK..LST....LG.D......K....L........
```

I have tried the following code:

```
awk '                               
match($0,/_=[A-Z]+/){              
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)    
  if(gsub(val,"&")==2){            
    print                           
    found=1                         
  }
  val=""                            
  next                              
}
found{                              
  found=""                          
  print                            
}
' test.fasta
```

The code returns with no value.

Comment: The `awk` script was adapted from <https://stackoverflow.com/a/60498903/8133920>.

Comment: Do you have GNU awk or POSIX awk?

Comment: @Quasímodo agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the equal from the regex in the second line:

```
match($0,/_[A-Z]+/){
```

Answer (score 1):

With `gawk` you can do:

```
$ awk -v RS=$'>' '{
                   cnt=patsplit($0, arr, "_[^/]+") 
                   if (cnt==2 && arr[1]==arr[2]) 
                        printf ">%s", $0
                  }' test.fasta
```